# NaN on array with user inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

Greetings i am a first month java script student and having issues creating a working array. I am trying to get input from a user use the parsefloat to change it from a string to an integer, pass it trough a function to find the middle value or a average of the middle value, but it keeps coming up as NaN, tried various different ways to check the values but it still refuses to accept them as integers, this is the code as it stands now. thank you again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> middle index </title>
        <script>
         function middleIndex() { 

            var index = [];
            index = [
                  parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value),
                  parseFloat(document.getElementById('input2').value),
                  parseFloat(document.getElementById('input3').value),
                  parseFloat(document.getElementById('input4').value),
                  parseFloat(document.getElementById('input5').value)
            ];

            var midindex = getMiddle(index);
            document.getElementById('output').value = midindex;
        };

        function getMiddle(list) {
           var s = list.map(function(v) {
               return v.values;}).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});

           var middle = Math.floor((s.lenth - 1) / 2);
           if (s.lenth % 2) {
               return s[middle];
           } else {
               return (s[middle] + s[middle +1]) / 2.0;
           }
        };
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Finding the middle value</h2>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="input3">
    <br>

    <input type="text" id="input4">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="input5">
    <br>
    <button onclick="middleIndex()">Middle</button>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="output">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "use the parsefloat to change it from a string to an integer". Shouldn't you use parseInt if you want an integer?

Comment: Html added per request

Comment: I though parse float changes what is place in the input boxes as the type text and change it to the integer no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have grammatical mistake in word length, it shouldn't be lenth but length in both cases.
2. return v.values - remove values
3. If all you want is to sort then you can use only sort function of javascript  var s = list.sort();

All code complete:

```
function getMiddle(list) {               
    var s = list.sort();
    var middle = Math.floor((s.length - 1) / 2);

    if (s.length % 2 == 0) {
         return s[middle];
    } else {
         return (s[middle] + s[middle + 1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify this answer.I think it may help.

```
function middleIndex() { 
    var index = [];
    var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(var i=1;i<inputTags.length+1;i++) {
        var x = 'input' + i;
        index.push(parseFloat(document.getElementById(x).value));
    }
}
```

So here i pushing all the values into index array.Use `return v` instead of using `return v.values`.
And also use `length` not `lenth`.

Comment: This also worked, it streamlined user input thank you.